# Possible unhandled promise rejection React Native

Tags: react-native, agora.io

We are trying to send morse code with the use of Agora API and React Native, it works when we are in the start-up channel but as soon as we switch channels it will stop working.
We use the following method to send morse code and to also hear it on your own device:

```
engine.sendStreamMessage(dataStreamId, 'dash');
beep.setCurrentTime(9.7);
beep.play();
```

The datastream ID remains the same when switching channels. We get the following error message:

```
    Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
Error: invalid argument
promiseMethodWrapper@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2242:45
sendStreamMessage@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:100044:47
dotMorsePressedFunc@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:98684:33
onPress@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:98876:46
onPress@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:69663:35
_performTransitionSideEffects@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:54930:22
_receiveSignal@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:54872:45
onResponderRelease@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:54781:34
invokeGuardedCallbackImpl@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:9137:21
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:9231:42
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:9235:36
executeDispatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:9307:48
executeDispatchesInOrder@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:9327:26
executeDispatchesAndRelease@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10402:35
forEach@[native code]
forEachAccumulated@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:9469:22
runEventsInBatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10426:27
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10505:25
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10481:42
batchedUpdates$1@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:21130:20
batchedUpdates@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10388:36
_receiveRootNodeIDEvent@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10480:23
receiveTouches@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10533:34
__callFunction@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2765:36
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2497:31
__guard@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2719:15
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2496:21
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

It is not clear what argument in what method is invalid? How can we check this?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Agora documentation createDataStream and sendStreamMessage return promises. Their types are declared:

```
createDataStream(reliable: boolean, ordered: boolean): Promise<number>
sendStreamMessage(streamId: number, message: string): Promise<void>
```

You should add a then and catch methods to handle your promise behavior.

```
var streamPromise = engine.sendStreamMessage(dataStreamId, 'dash')
streamPromise.then(() => { ...do something})
streamPromise.catch(error => ...handle error)
```